# Can't redirect to view controller from AppDelegate when there's no logged in PFUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

My root view controller is for logged in users only, therefore I have to redirect the non logged in users to the sign up/log in screen. I've tried to this from the `AppDelegate`, but my implementation doesn't works. When I launch the app it doesn't perform the `presentLoginViewControllerAnimated` method and crashes because there's no logged in users. (The Dev log also doesn't displayed)

Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        NSLog(@"Dev log");
        [self presentLoginViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)presentLoginViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginController animated:animated completion:nil];
}
```

If somebody sees what did I wrong, or did something like this in the past I would really appreciate any help. In brief, I just like to hide the registration required view controllers from non logged in users. If there's any other easier solution it could be good too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to present your root view controller to your user whether they're logged in or not, so you may need to change what you're using as your root view controller.  Try using your login view as the root view controller and then redirect them to your main view controller when they are logged in.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would solve the problem from a software design perspective. Make your login controller in you storyboard the initial view controller. In the login controller do your check

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        NSLog(@"Dev log");
        [self presentLoginViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

and change your presentViewController method to load your "logged in" view and also he last line to:

```
[self presentViewController:loginController animated:animated completion:nil];
```